# What happens if I continue to use the EOL release (20.10)?

Tags: apt, 20.10

I was working on ubuntu 20.04, but at some point it was upgraded to 20.10. (There was no notice.) So, in etc/apt/sources.list, I changed the CODENAME to groovy->focal and tried to use apt update and upgrade. do.And it goes well.

If I use the EOL Release, is the only problem that I can't install package upgrade and install?

Or is there another problem?

Comment: No problems if your box is offline... If online you put yourself, and others close to your (*connected via networks*) at risk...

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 1):

An EOL Release does not receive updates, including security updates. The word "only" in your question, shows that you underestimate a risk that is very real and not to be underestimated.

If your computer is connected to a network (e.g. the internet) you do **not** want to use an EOL release.