# can't do apt-get update

Tags: networking, apt

I can't do apt-get update. It throws me all these errors:

```
Obj:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                     
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease
Ign:4 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:6 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Err:7 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:8 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:9 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
E: El repositorio «http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release» ya no tiene un archivo Release.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

I did a ping to this ip: 91.189.91.38 and I get a response without problems.

Comment: Can you open the URL ( http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu ) in a browser ?

Comment: looks like you've got an outdated version of Ubuntu - but you did not care to mention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if I continue to use the EOL release (20.10)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403173/what-happens-if-i-continue-to-use-the-eol-release-20-10)

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Answer (score 2):

You’re using 20.10 which reached end of life just over a year ago.

It won’t update and is therefore not safe to use.

Have a look at this question and answer for ways to upgrade to a supported version. [How upgrade Ubuntu 20.10 after its EOL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361262/how-upgrade-ubuntu-20-10-after-its-eol)

I’d recommend installing an LTS version (current one is 22.04LTS) so you won’t run into similar problems for close to 5 years.